# Incomplete type error when using std::vector with structs

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I'm working with c++ STL vectors, and have a vector of structures called *projectileList.* I'm trying to iterate through the vector, getting and setting values in the struts as I iterate, but my code refuses to compile, with the error 'Incomplete type is not allowed.'

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong:

Code:

ProjectHandeler.h:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DataTypes.h"
#include <vector>

class ProjectileHandeler {

private:

    int activeObjects;

    std::vector<projectile> projectileList;

    void projectileUpdater();


public:
    ProjectileHandeler(projectile* input[], int projectileCount);

    ~ProjectileHandeler();

};

#endif
```

projectileHandeler.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DataTypes.h"
#include "ProjectHandeler.h"
#include <vector> 

ProjectileHandeler::ProjectileHandeler(projectile* input[], int projectileCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < projectileCount; i++)
    {
        projectileList.push_back(*input[i]);
        activeObjects += 1;
    }

    //NO extra slots. Not that expensive.
    projectileList.resize(projectileList.size());
}

void ProjectileHandeler::projectileUpdater()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < projectileList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (projectileList[i].isEditing == true)
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: change `*projectileList[i].isEditing` to `projectileList[i].isEditing`

Comment: Missing semicolon. Voted to close as simple typographical error.

Comment: Please post real code

Comment: Updated with full code owing to continued inability to unresolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine (tested it here: http://codepad.org/cWn6MPJq):

```
#include <vector>

struct projectile {
    bool isEditing;

    };


class ProjectileHandeler {

private:
    std::vector<projectile> projectileList;

void projectileUpdater()
{
    //This bit loops to infinity and beyond! ...or at least untill the handeler is destroyed.
    while (true)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < projectileList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (projectileList[i].isEditing == true) //Throws Incomplete type error
                break;
        }
    }

}
};

int main()
{
}
```

Notice the removal of `*`, correct type of loop variable and removal of extra class specifier.

Comment: Thanks for that. The extra class specifiers there because the actual code is split between a header and source. Having updated the loop varible and removed the pointer (I see that mistake now, cheers,) the if (projectileList[i].isEditing == true) now throws Error: "left of .isEditing must be class/struct/union.

Comment: If the struct is unknown at that point perhaps the issue is lost when you cut and paste snippets from different files into the question. My snippet compiles fine (see link). Do you include the header declaring the struct where your class implementation is?